# MOXy (un)marshalling of empty collections inconsistent?

Tags: java, collections, jaxb, jax-rs, moxy

I'm using JAX-RS/Jersey (2.10.1) with JAXB/EclipseLink MOXy (2.5.2) and have two web service methods like this:

```
@GET
@Path( "{login}" )
@Produces( { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML } )
public User getUserByLogin( @PathParam( "login" ) String login )
{
  User result = userFacade.getUserByLoginWithAuthorizationData( login );
  return result;
}

@POST
@Consumes( { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML } )
public void createUser( User newUser )
{
  userFacade.create( newUser );
}
```

A `User` has a many-to-many relation with a `Role`, both of which are also JPA entities, like this:

```
private List<Role> roles;

@ManyToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
@JoinTable( name = "usersroles", schema = "public", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn( name = "user_dbid", nullable = false ) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn( name = "role_dbid", nullable = false ) } )
@XmlElementWrapper( name = "roles" )
@XmlElement( name = "role", type = Role.class )
@XmlInverseReference( mappedBy = "users" )
public List<Role> getRoles()
{
  return this.roles;
}
```

I have configured MOXy with this setting to marshal empty collections:

```
MoxyJsonConfig config;
config.setMarshalEmptyCollections( true );
```

This gives me the following desired result when I query a `User` without any associated `Role`s (password as clear text for testing purposes only):

```
{"user": {
   "roles": [],
   "dbid": 33,
   "login": "test@acme.com",
   "password": "test",
   "version": 1
}}
```

Because `User` is a JPA entity, EclipseLink always initializes `roles` when the object is populated from the database, i.e. it is not `null` but an empty list (Vector) in this example. However, if I send an HTTP POST with the exact same JSON object, my `newUser` object is unmarshalled with an unitialized `roles` list, i.e. it is `null`. I would like to have an empty list though.

I have tried to use `@XmlNullPolicy`, the `nillable`/`required` setting on the `@XmlElementWrapper`, all to no avail. Is this intended behaviour, am I missing out on something? I know about the `afterUnmarshal` callback and `@XmlJavaTypeAdapater`, but I'd rather not use those as I'd expect the behavior to be consistent out of the box.